# HTML Form Pattern Regex

Tags: html, regex, validation

I'm trying to have a Reg Exp for the following:

8 characters min
 
1 uppercase (at least)
 
1 lowercase (at least)
 
1 digit (at least)
 
Excluding: + @ &

I have the following but I can't seem to have the right combo of group/sub-group to make them work together:

```
[^+@&](?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])).{8,}
```

I need guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [anchors](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html#caret) and place the negated class after your assertions.

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[^+@&]{8,}$
```